# Is there a c# event that I can subscribe to make sure my code always executes when the session ends?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a simple Alexa skill using c# and the Alexa.net package.
I need my skill to execute some code every time a session ends. 
Is there anything like a regular c# event that I can subscribe to in order to make sure my code always executes when the session ends?

So far I have tried utilizing the AMAZON. Stop Event. However, what I would really like is a way to make sure that my code executes regardless of how the session is ended. Not just when it ended on purpose by the user. IE. if the session times out I want the code to execute as well.

Comment: How about SessionEndedRequest? https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html#sessionendedrequest

Comment: Hmm that might just do it, i am at work right now but i´ll try it out when i get home :) .. Thank you for your response.